# angular js - point ng-model to one property of an object initially, but sync back to another

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a kendo ui grid, where each row is editable, and in a specific column I want to sync the inputs data to the underlying grid data (an array of objects) while the user is typing, and bind the input value to one specific property on the data Item, `amount` in this case. I have accomplished that first part using ng-model. When the user clicks on a button to pay, I want `amount` (also a property in the data item) to be set to another property's value (which also is in the same object) which is called `amountDue.due`.

This is what I tried, it is working OK in the first case where the user has not clicked on the button to pay. However, I can't figure out the case when the user has clicked pay - the nested if below is not working. in angularjs, how do I point an ng-model to one property of an object (or in this case a nested property, `amountDue.due`) on init and have this saved in another property (in this case `amount`)?

So in this case if `paymentClicked` I want the ng-model to take an initial value of `amountDue.due`, but I want that value saved in the `amount` property. I am trying to do this with angular as much as possible and not kendo.

```
 if (columnName.field == 'amount') {
    angular.extend(columnName, { template: '<input type="text" class="k-textbox" ng-model="$ctrl.dataSourceName[dataItem.index].amount"/>' })
    if (paymentClicked) {
      angular.extend(columnName, { template: '<input type="text" class="k-textbox" ng-init="$ctrl.dataSourceName[dataItem.index].amount = dataItem.amountDue.due" ng-model="$ctrl.dataSourceName[dataItem.index].amountApplied" ng-change="$ctrl.change($event)" />' })
    }
  }
```

Comment: this doesn't sound like the angular way to do things at all;  angular is pretty solidly in the one model property for one field.  without seeing what your grid looks like, my first pass at this would probably be to use `ng-change()` on the `paymentClicked` and within that, set the value of the model that's already bound to the other field (initially set to `null`, likely).

Comment: if you want them synchronized in realtime, then you would probably use `$watch()` to update the second field when the first field's value changes.  Those are a couple ideas, anyway.

Comment: Why not set the `$scope.dataSourceName[index].amount = dataItem.amountDue.due` in the `paymentClicked` click event handler. I agree with Claies, switching out ngModel is not a suitable approach

Comment: @KScandrett working with kendo was confusing me... you're right. please post as an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd set `$scope.dataSourceName[index].amount = dataItem.amountDue.due` in the `paymentClicked` click event handler.